# Store related items with many-to-many relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, e-commerce, product, voyager

I'm overriding voyager admin panel & trying to store multiple related items in add new product form.
My view is

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
   <label class="control-label">Related Products</label>
   <select class="form-control chosen-select">
    @foreach($products as $product)
     <option class="form-control" value="{{$product->id}}" name="related_id[]"> {{$product->name}} </option>
    @endforeach
   </select>
 </div>
```

Product Model

```
public function related() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'related_products', 'product_id', 'related_id');
    }
```

RelatedProduct Model

```
class RelatedProduct extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'related_products';
    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'related_id'];

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'related_products', 'product_id', 'related_id');
    }
}
```

Product Controller

```
if($data->save()) {
            $productId = $data->id;
            $products = [];
            for ($i=0; $i < $request->related_id; $i++) { 
            
                array_push($products, [
                    'product_id' => $productId,
                    'related_id' => $request->related_id[$i]
                ]);
            }
            

            // Related product pivot table bulk insertion
            RelatedProduct::insert($products);
            
            // response stuff
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'last_insert_id' => $data->id,
                'related_id'    =>  $request->related_id,
        ], 200);

        }
```

Everything is working fine but related_id is going null.

Comment: try   for ($i=0; $i < count($request->related_id); $i++) {

            array_push($products, [
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'related_id' => $request->related_id[$i]
            ]);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing loop.Since you haven't mentioned count of `related_id`.that might be the reason.

```
  for ($i=0; $i < count((array)$request->related_id); $i++) {

            array_push($products, [
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'related_id' => $request->related_id[$i]
            ]);
        }
```

**Updated**
also you have error in select

```
 <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="related_id[]">
    @foreach($products as $product)
     <option class="form-control" value="{{$product->id}}" > {{$product->name}} </option>
    @endforeach
   </select>
```

Comment: It's showing the following error:
**count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**

Comment: The output is still same: **{"success":true,"last_insert_id":2086,"related_id":null}**

Comment: dd($request->related_id) before loop .checj what you get

Comment: its just **null**

Comment: it means from request its so it null.

Comment: What is the solution then? I've put the view also. Can you check please?

Comment: pass related_id from form .

Comment: That is the main problem sir. I've tried everything. The view is also showing in the form but related_id is still null. How can I pass related_id?

Comment: is Related Products dropdown shows value ?

Comment: Yes its showing all the products in table. I've call it from ```public function index() { $products = Product::all(); }```
But now I'm storing it in ```public function store(Request $request) ```

Comment: Yes its showing the related_id now. You solved it Thank you so much.